# uninstall only one xcode instance

Tags: xcode, uninstallation

I have two versions of XCode installed, one is version 3, and the other is the latest beta version which installed under a different directory.

I have read many examples how to uninstall Xcode using a method similar to the following:

> sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

But I am not sure if it will uninstall both installations or just the one I invoked the uninstall tool on?

How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each installation directory will have a Library folder. Use:

> sudo [Path of version you want to
>   remove]/Library/uninstall-devtools
>   --mode=all

This will remove the version that is installed in that directory.